# Android meterpreter payload crashes app

Tags: android, metasploit, injection, meterpreter

I'm trying to inject a reverse_tcp meterpreter payload into my own app for educational purposes.

Loading the raw payload apk on my phone works over LAN/WAN.

I injected the payload manually by decompiling both apk using apktool and put the Payload.smali file into com/metasploit/stage. What was interesting is that my MainActivity.smali file is incredibly small, and there were no protected functions. There was a public onCreate that called a private and empty n_onCreate native function.

After the call to the private n_onCreate I added the invoke static call to the payload. This crashes my app and I don't understand why. I also don't understand why the smali file is so small. Here is the smali file https://pastebin.com/jjX8TCMy - Line 171 is my invoke static call to the payload

I also don't know how to access the crash log (if any) that is produced when my app crashes like that.

I used Xamarin.Android to create the app if that makes any difference, and it might explain the private native methods that are seemingly empty?

What am I doing wrong in injecting this payload to the apk?